# Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement using an object

Tags: c#, foreach

I have the following code that was converted from vb to C#

```
    private void LoadDropDownList()
{
    DropDownList location = (DropDownList) Form.FindControl("ddlLocation_ID");
    DropDownList vendorID = (DropDownList) Form.FindControl("ddlVendor_ID");

    //-- Load the Sales Locations
    dtDataList_v10_r1.List objList = new dtDataList_v10_r1.List();
    DataSet ds = default(DataSet);
    DataView dvActiveLocations = null;

    ds = objList.GetSalesLocationDataset(mobjSecurity.SQLDatabase, mobjSecurity.Inst_ID);
    if ((ds != null)) {
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) {
            dvActiveLocations = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);  //changed to square brackets per c# syntax 10/9/15 Max //
            dvActiveLocations.RowFilter = "status='A'";
        }
    }

    //ddlLocation_ID.DataSource = dvActiveLocations;
    //ddlLocation_ID.DataTextField = "ChannelName";
    //ddlLocation_ID.DataValueField = "Channel_ID";
    //ddlLocation_ID.DataBind();
    location.DataSource = dvActiveLocations;  // changed to reference control and c# syntax 10/9/15 Max //
    location.DataTextField = "ChannelName";  // changed to reference control and c# syntax 10/9/15 Max //
    location.DataValueField = "Channel_ID";  // changed to reference control and c# syntax 10/9/15 Max //
    location.DataBind();  // changed to reference control and c# syntax 10/9/15 Max //



    //-- Load the Available Auction downloads
    dtIntegration_v10_r1.Vendor objVendor = default(dtIntegration_v10_r1.Vendor);
    dtIntegration_v10_r1.Vendor[] objVendors = null;
    dtIntegration_v10_r1.Auctions objAuctions = new dtIntegration_v10_r1.Auctions( ref mobjSecurity);  //added ref key word 10/9/15 Max //
    objVendors = objAuctions.Vendors;



    foreach (objVendor in objVendors)
        if (objVendor.HasVendorRelationship == true)
        {
            //ddlVendor_ID.Items.Insert(0, objVendor.Name);
            //ddlVendor_ID.Items(0).Value = objVendor.Vendor_ID;
            vendorID.Items.Insert(0, objVendor.Name);
            vendorID.Items[0].Value = Convert.ToString(objVendor.Vendor_ID);  //changed to reference control and facilitate conversion to string 10/9/15 Max //
        }
}
```

I get the following error when I execute it

> Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement

Now I realize that a proper statement should look like this

> foreach (var somevar in object) ....

I tried this syntax and it throws this error

> A local variable named 'objVendor' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'objVendor', which is already used in a parent or current scope to denote something else

So I am curious how to fix this particular error.  I couldn't find it in any of the topics here so I thought I would ask

Comment: Why not give it a different name?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman  I did try that and it seems to give the same error even when I change the reference name and the variable in the foreach statement

Comment: Thanks for the downvote although I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With foreach, you need to setup the type for the parameter, as so.

```
foreach(dtIntegration_v10_r1.Vendor objvendor in objVendors)
{
    //your code.
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the correct answer. You still have two variables with the same name.

Comment: I changed the name slightly, in the other one the "V" is capital but in this foreach loop the "V" is lowercase. Although yes, in the original code the same name was used for both.

Comment: @Rariolu Oh, right. Sorry about that. You shouldn't be naming stuff so similarly to avoid confusion. I got confused :-)

Comment: I was just using a similar name to the original code, take this up with the guy who asked the question if you have such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You already delcared something named `objVendor` here:

```
dtIntegration_v10_r1.Vendor objVendor = default(dtIntegration_v10_r1.Vendor);
```

You need to pick a unique name in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is very straightforward. You already declared a variable named `objVendor` which is visible inside the for loop:

```
dtIntegration_v10_r1.Vendor objVendor = default(dtIntegration_v10_r1.Vendor);
```

Now here:

```
foreach (var objVendor in objVendors)
    if (objVendor.HasVendorRelationship == true)
```

which `objVendor` should be referenced in the second line? The one declared at the declaration of the loop or the second one? There is no way for the compiler to guess correctly, thus your code is incorrect. Fix it by giving the loop variable a different name.

```
foreach (var xyz in objVendors)
```

> Now I realize that a proper statement should look like this
>
> ```
> foreach (var somevar in object) ....
> ```

Not necessarily. You can insert the actual type name instead of `var`. Most of the time both will suffice.